# Inheriting an interface from a base abstract class and IDisposable's correct place

Tags: c#

I have the following structure below.

#### Questions:

- Is IStrategy interface needed at all? Because I've seen people doing same thing I did - there is a Start method which is defined as an `abstract` in the base class and they exposed it with an interface which defines it as well. However, other people think that it is enough to specify the `Start` method only in the base class and the interface is not needed at all, because the code gets more complicated. What's your opinion?
- I'm defining `IBinanceClient` and `IBinanceSocketClient` in the base class and they both have to be disposed at some point. In my code below, I implemented the IDisposable in the derived class, but however, I think it's a better decision to move it in the base class, because BinanceClient is defined there. What do you think?

```cs
public interface IStrategy
{
    public void Start(Bot bot, CancellationToken token);
}

public abstract class StrategyBase : IStrategy
{
    public IBinanceClient Client { get; }
    public IBinanceSocketClient SocketClient { get; }

    protected StrategyBase(string apiKey, string secretKey)
    {
        Client = new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions()
        {
            ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(apiKey, secretKey),
            AutoTimestamp = true,
            AutoTimestampRecalculationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
        });

        SocketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions()
        {
            ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(apiKey, secretKey),
            AutoReconnect = true,
            ReconnectInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        });
    }

    public List<BinanceStreamTick> Tickers { get; set; }

    // Methods that all strategies use
    public void GetTickers()
    {
        ... implementation
    }

    public abstract void Start(Bot bot, CancellationToken token); // ???
}

public class CompositeStrategy : StrategyBase, IDisposable
{
    public CompositeStrategy(string apiKey, string secretKey) : base(apiKey, secretKey)
    {
    }

    public override void Start(Bot bot, CancellationToken token)
    {
        ... implementation
    }

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Client != null)
                Client.Dispose();

            if (SocketClient != null)
            {
                SocketClient.UnsubscribeAll();
                SocketClient.Dispose();
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

Other way, based on @Wiktor Zychla's comment.

```cs
public interface IStrategy
{
    public void Start(Bot bot, CancellationToken token);
}

public abstract class StrategyBase : IStrategy, IDisposable
{
    public IBinanceClient Client { get; }
    public IBinanceSocketClient SocketClient { get; }

    protected StrategyBase(string apiKey, string secretKey)
    {
        Client = new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions()
        {
            ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(apiKey, secretKey),
            AutoTimestamp = true,
            AutoTimestampRecalculationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
        });

        SocketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions()
        {
            ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(apiKey, secretKey),
            AutoReconnect = true,
            ReconnectInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        });
    }

    public List<BinanceStreamTick> Tickers { get; set; }

    public void GetTickers()
    {
        ... implementation
    }

    public abstract void Start(Bot bot, CancellationToken token);

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Client != null)
                Client.Dispose();

            if (SocketClient != null)
            {
                SocketClient.UnsubscribeAll();
                SocketClient.Dispose();
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}

public class CompositeStrategy : StrategyBase
{
    public CompositeStrategy(string apiKey, string secretKey) : base(apiKey, secretKey)
    {
    }

    public override void Start(Bot bot, CancellationToken token)
    {
        ... implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) nothing wrong with the interface. Could be useful elsewhere. 2) move `IDisposable` to the parent or even make your interface inherit it so that `Dispose` is always there, even if empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you need the `IStrategy` interface or not depends on the context where you are using this, so is not clear. However, having `IStrategy` with a `Start ()` method and `StrategyBase` with an `abstract` `Start()` method seems like duplication, which would suggest you only need the base class.

Regarding where to put the `Dispose()`, the general rule is objects should be disposed in the same class where they are created. (In the same method, if possible, but that's only for very short-lived objects and not the case here.)

You don't show where `SocketClient` and `Client` are created, but they are declared in `StrategyBase`, which would suggest that is where they should be disposed.